# How do I unzip an archive file via ZipArchive

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

So far after looking of multiple examples of how to unzip a file i'm a little confused on what i'm missing for this to work now.

Im using WordPress and AdvancedCustomFields to designate what kind of file i'm going to be uploading. I need to unzip this file and figure out the internal files to use one as a source.

```
} else if(get_sub_field('media_type') == 'Zip'){
        /* Get Path Name */
        $file = get_sub_field('file');
        $pieces = explode("/", $file);
        $lastZip =  end($pieces);
        array_pop($pieces ); //removes last
        $path = implode("/", $pieces);
        $path = $path."/";
        /* Get Name of File and concat .png */
        $last = explode(".", $lastZip);
        $last = $last[0].".png";
        /* Append new filename to proper pathing */
        $pathFile = $path.$last;

        $zip = new ZipArchive;

        $zip->open($lastZip, ZipArchive::CREATE);
        print_r($zip);
        if ($zip === TRUE) {
            $zip->extractTo($path);
            $zip->close();
            echo 'File extracted to: $path';
        } else {
            echo "does not work!";
        }


      ?><span><img src="<?php echo $pathFile; ?>" /></span>
    <?php
    }
```

My outcome of `print_r($zip)` is:

```
ZipArchive Object (
    [status] => 0 
    [statusSys] => 0 
    [numFiles] => 0 
    [filename] => /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/example.zip 
    [comment] => 
)
```

Comment: Why do you specify `ZipArchive::CREATE` if you want to _extract_ an existing archive?

Comment: Saw ::CREATE used in a few examples. Prior to using CREATE the ZipArchive Object didn't give me a filename. The object was completely empty prior. Figured at least recognizing the filename is one step closer.

Comment: I suggest you start reading the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.open.php Believe me, it offers much more precise information than many examples you find out there.

Comment: I made a change to the original code from $zip->open to $res = $zip->open and checked if $res === TRUE. I went through the documentation and added a switch with a case for each error at the bottom. I got a ER_OPEN : Can't open file error. I checked this files properties which is 644. Still confused on what this page even can offer me still.

Comment: Ah, so probably the actual issue is not the php code, but the file system access which fails. I'd say you have to follow all nodes of the path up to the file to check if the http process is allowed to enter the directories. Oh, and obviously it could also be that the zip file is protected by a password. Not sure if ZipArchive can handle that.

Comment: I pulled down the Zip file and opened it. It's not password protected. Do you have an idea of how to check down the nodes of the path to check if the http process is allowed to enter the directories?

Comment: Well, what about using `ls -l`? Or you switch your user id to that of the http server and try to open the file then.

Comment: Hey Arkascha, how do I switch my user id to that of the http server? Also how do I find the user id of the http server? I also just tried getting to this file via relative pathing.

Comment: Relative or absolute is not the issue if you target the same location, since it _is_ the same folders and files you try to access. Switching your user id is done with the `su` command. However you may have to allow login to that account first, this depends a bit on what distribution you use. To find out what account the http server actually uses either look into the process list (`ps aux`) or into the launching script (something like `/etc/init.d/apache2` or similar).